# Where to store a key in android?

Tags: android, security, key

I am developing a mobile app which retrieve some data from web server via web service call. Calls to different web services are down using an API key. Now the question is how and where this API key must be stored? It is worth noting communication is taken over HTTPS protocol.

Comment: In eclipse you stored it in the properties file, in android studio you store it in build.config file

Answer (score 0):

You can use res->values->strings.xml

But if you want to make it more secure then you can use Api. Suppose you have a api named www.myapiKeysHolder.com. This api rechive a post data "app_pkg" and if this is your app package name then it provide your api key as response. And then you can save this key in your sqlite Database or Share performance.
Some sample come for you:

```
// Create AsycHttpClient object
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
// Http Request Params Object
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("app_pkg", getPackageName().toString());

client.post("www.myapiKeysHolder.com", params, new   
   AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
         String api=response; //Api give your Api Key
         updateSQLite("api_key",api);
    }
});
```

To support this code you will need this jar file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofjcyo7zz1q86p7/android-async-http-1.3.1.jar

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: As best of my knowledge, saving API key in SQLite DB is not secure because one can extract that data and access to users information by calling web service.

Comment: You can use  Share performance or even you don't need to save it if you want. For this you need to call api every time when user need.